# How to make a data member get inherited in one class but not the other

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, data-structures

I'm making an abstract Linked List in C++

Which have a node like this:

```
template <typename T>
class LL{
    protected:
        enum {MAX = 512};
        class Node{
            protected: 
                Node* next;
                Node* prev;
            public:
                const T& data;
                Node(){}
                ...
        };
...
};
```

Now I want to make a Singly linked list from this abstract class that should only get the next pointer and a Doubly linked list that gets both
How can I achieve this?

I tried making Node:

```
class Node{
    protected: 
        Node* next;
    public:
        const T& data;
        Node(){}
    ...
};
```

Then inside doubly Linked list made a BiNode that inherits from Node and have a prev pointer but that makes a new class and invalidates all the functions that return Node

Comment: Why is reversing the concept not an option? I.e. you cannot drop something via inheriting, but you can add something. So do not attempt to inherit single-linked from double-linked. Instead inherit double-linked from sinlge linked and add the second pointer.

Comment: Inheriting something in one derived class but not in the other, that's not how OOP works. But you could make the node type another template parameter of your list class template. (Just yesterday, I saw the [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) where this approach was used for the storage containers of vertices and edges.)

Comment: @Yunnosch I see, thanks, I forgot that the functions that work for Node will also work for BiNode (Bi-directional Node, which will be derived from Node) we can always pass derived class to Base class functions :-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat That looks interesting I'll look into that (:

Comment: I must admit that BGL is not the most easy stuff. However, they explained their concept thoroughly so that, at least, this part could be of help.

Comment: I think you should move the common base class out of both. Inheriting double from single linked list or the other way round seems wrong: Inheritance suggests an "is-a" relationship, but neither is a single linked list a double linked list nor the other way round. They are both linked lists (which is what your abstract base should be).

Answer (score -1):

The approach utilised to handle this complexity is known as "Template Specialisation."
The code uses the LL class template with an additional boolean template option, DoublyLinked, to determine whether the linked list is single or doubly linked. It employs std::conditional_t to conditionally select the Node type based on this boolean. Instances of LL can be created for singly or doubly linked lists using LL<int, false> and LL<int, true>, respectively. This design facilitates code reuse for both types of linked lists without the need for separate classes.[VISUAL STUDIO CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qgs0.png)

[image]

Comment: 1. [Please attach the code as text, not a picture.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2752075). 2. I don't think this actually works. First of all, `conditional_t` is useless because it's never reached with `DoublyLinked == true` due to the specialization. Second, the base `LL<T, false>` doesn't see `using NodeType` from the derived class, and always uses its own definition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).